# print the contents of PHP variable as text string in HTML

Tags: php, html, variables

in a wordpress php script, I have the following:

```
echo '<div class="slide-media">' . $slide_media . 
     '</div><!--/.slide-media-->' . "\n";               }
```

I want to see the contents of what is inside `$slide_media` variable.
Basically, so I can add a link to the image.

Is there a variable to plain text function?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you're outputting raw HTML to a HTML document (and you want it shown as `<b>text</b>` instead of **text**), you can use [`htmlentities($string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
htmlentities($slide_media);
```

If your string is UTF8, you might have to specify this (*if your PHP version is 5.4+, you don't have to specify UTF-8, as it's default*):

```
htmlentities($slide_media, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

You can also strip all HTML tags from the variable by using [`strip_tags($string)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
strip_tags($slide_media);
```

Answer (score 3):

To see what is within a variable (maybe it is in array, an object or something else) use print_r($slide_media); or var_dump($slide_media);

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($slide_media, true) . '</pre>';
```

Or maybe

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export(array_map('htmlentities', $slide_media), true) . '</pre>';
```

If $slidemedia is an array with html content.

Answer (score 0):

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) Prints human-readable information about a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print_r($slide_media); ?>
```

should do the trick for you.